# curl ethereum -d question

Tags: external-api

How can I change the following to php format? what means the -d @...jaon, it means the parameter for this curl is json and post to the url?
cat call.json
{
    "private": "3ca40...",
    "gas_limit": 20000 
}

curl -d @call.json -s https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/contracts/0eb688e79698d645df015cf2e9db5a6fe16357f1/greet?token=YOURTOKEN

Comment: Hello, your question seems to be more focused towards PHP instead of Ethereum, try on a php stack exchange, you'll be more likely to get your answer.